# Push updated code to installs

Tags: auto-update

I am trying to automate an update mechanism which will push updates to all its installed instances. All the code stays on the server (no third party installs), however each install is independant from other installs

eg/

```
/webbase/client1
/webbase/client2
/webbase/client3
...
```

Other then each install having its own config file, the code is the same. What would you consider to be the best way to automatically push updates to all the installed instances?. The entire application is database driven at the moment, and coded in PHP

Answer (score 1):

First small assumption:
Your "webapp" is purly code or mostly-code.
Your "webapp" do not change itself, or changes are limited to external resources.
Your "webapp" do not change database design during updates.

Simplest answer would be to set up dcvs, and with one command you would send all code to clients. As side effect you would gain ability to roll back update if needed. In modern cvs there is no problem with setting multiple repost you update to, and adding new ones is also trivial. Setting up dcvs is also not a problem.

So on dev machine (or machine that code visit just before pushing update to clients) you set up cvs, and then with one command you deploy changes to clients. However this will push static changes (and will not update database!), so in order to do dynamic changes after merely coping changes you will need additional scripts (and those you also can put in repo so they also get updated!). Then set up repos and dcvs server on clients machine. And your are ready to start deploying.

You can also look for dedicated (to your language+framework) deployment solution (there should be plenty of those for PHP, though they may not be free of costs).

Comment if you need any clarification.